# Dir Paginate Directive appending data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am creating a app using angularJs. In my project i am using dir paginate directive from here: https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination
 I am using dropdown to fetch data from api and passing to the view. But the new record set appends to the previous data.
When I use ng-repreat , the code is working fine
 Here is My code:

```
<select class="selectbox_menulist" ng-model="flow.flow_id" ng-change="network.getFlowByID(flow)">
                                <option value="">{{'popup.configureFlowView.form.select' | translate}}</option>
                                <option ng-repeat="flow in flowIds" value="{{flow.id}}">{{flow.id}}</option>
                            </select>

<tr ng-if="contracts.length" dir-paginate="contract in contracts | itemsPerPage: contractsPerPage track by contract.contractid"-->
                                <td>{{contract.contractid}}</td>
                                <td>{{contract.contractStatus}}</td>
                                <td>{{contract.bandwidth}}</td>
                                <td>{{contract["contract-end-time"] | date: 'medium' : actualTimeZone}}</td>
                                <td>{{contract["contract-start-time"] | date: 'medium' : actualTimeZone}}</td>
                                <td>{{contract["renewal-option"] | renewalName | translate}} </td>
                                <td>{{contract.price}}</td>
                                <td><span class="icon_edit anchor" ng-click="network.contract.editContract($event,contract)"></span></td>
                            </tr dir-paginate>
```

Controller Code is:

```
networkService.getContracts(linkId).then(function(response){
                        $scope.contracts = response.contracts;
                        console.log($scope.contracts);

                    });
```